# Guitar wiring ground connection

Tags: ground, wiring

I am rewiring an old used guitar, typically you solder all the grounds to the switch or the pot case, connecting also all the cases to have a common ground.  Has anyone tried a PCB strip with screw connectors on it to make a single ground?  This would avoid heating the components while soldering.
Would the copper strip pick up noise?

Comment: Components are generally tolerant of the heat needed to solder them. Do you have particularly unusual ones that aren't?

Comment: Save the demonic thoughts to playing flattened fifths. Just solder them up.

Comment: In fact soldering is not the most reliable form of connection, especially not for things that vibrate! spring-type terminals and crimp connectors are much more reliable. Thats why they are used by professionals. Maybe you can think of a design that uses this stuff

Comment: @schnedan please provide a link to the type of connection you mean.

Comment: spring-type terminals are known under the brand name: wago clamps - just google it...

Answer (score 0):

Ground wiring on the guitar should ensure that the pick-up body, pick-up common, commons / bodies of potentiometers and the ground wire for the bridge get terminated at the 'common' terminal of the output jack.

Grounding would be automatic through the guitar output cable sheath, amplifier input jack 'common' and chassis ground.

Soldering would ensure reliable connections, obviating the need for a strip with screw connectors.

Comment: instead of soldering in various points on the back of the pots, as I found it, I decided to bring all the grounds together, wrapping the cables around each other and soldering that bunch.  It seems to work well, no noise in the amp.  Thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: That's great, freman1952!

Comment: what does common mean in this context? Most people refer to the connections at the output jack as ground and hot/live

Comment: @codecowboy, The ‘common’ terminal of a device is one that is common to its input as well as its output. In this context, that device would be the potentiometer, with its common terminal serving as the guitar ‘common’ to which the strings and shields would also be connected. With the amplifier ‘common’ being its grounded chassis, the strings would also be earthed and unwanted noise pick-up would be avoided.